# Java: How to avoid noise redundancy when use SnakeYaml?

Tags: java, snakeyaml

I have `yaml` file which I create through Java.

```
--- !!com.test.users.Configuration
config:
  userList: !!set
    ? name: John
      age: 18
    : null
    ? name: Axel
      age: 14
    : null
  defaultUser:
    name: Bob
    age: 15
```

Here is my SnakeYML code

```
DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
options.setDefaultScalarStyle(DumperOptions.ScalarStyle.PLAIN);
options.setPrettyFlow(true);
options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
options.setAllowReadOnlyProperties(true);
options.setExplicitStart(true);
yml = new Yaml(options);

FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path);
yml.dump(obj, writer);
```

The question is how to exclude all these redundant `!!noise
com.test.users.Configuration`, `?`, `: null`, `!!set`?

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
Representer representer = new Representer();
representer.addClassTag(com.test.users.Configuration.class, Tag.MAP);
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(representer);
```

2) use List and not Set to avoid `!!set` and `:null`